# Regex with varying whitespaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write Regex to find lines in a files where commands are not using absolute paths. Unfortunately, there are spacing issues with these lines.

```
// PATHS
pathmunge /absolute/path
  pathmunge   ~not/absolute/path
 pathmunge           /absolute/path


// matches

  pathmunge   ~not/absolute/path
```

My expression matches the lines where there are spaces at the beginning and before `pathmunge` string, but it doesn't find the lines with variable-length whitespace but without a "/" as the next non-whitespace character.

So far, I have:

```
^(?=\s+pathmunge)\s+(?!\/).*$
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's going wrong?

Comment: It's unable to match a whole line without '/'. When I try it on online regex evaluators, it would only match until "*spaces*  pathmunge   *spaces*" but not the rest of the line.

Comment: The pattern and matching string you gave [come back just fine on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7h1B2C/1)

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead? It's a nonsense here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: It also matches [3rd line](https://regex101.com/r/7h1B2C/2)

Answer (score 1):

For a regex, I would do:

```
^(?:[[:blank:]]*pathmunge[[:blank:]]+([^\s\/].*$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rOXofc/5/)

The key element is the `[^\s\/]` which matches a single character other than a horizontal space or a `\n` or `/` start of any absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lookahead and make the space possessive:

```
^\s*pathmunge\s++(?!\/).*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iakSiY/1)